# Classification with CNN/LSTM/RNN

Tags: python, r, deep-learning

My dataset has a number of numerical input, and 1 categorical (factor) output, and I want to train the model with CNN/RNN/LSTM to predict the output.

My data looks like:

```
input1 input2 ... input_n  output
2 1.2 ... -0.44 "b"
1 0.2 ... 3.2 "f"
3 1 ... 2.1 "a"
```

I tried with Keras and lasagne in Python, but did not succeed. I could not find a runnable example with my dataset, but I thought that this type of task should be basic (based on a set of input, predict the output).

Could you point me out an example that use the dataset similar with my dataset? Any programming language will be help.

Comment: Yes the task is typical classification problem. Try python wrapper of tensor flow in scikit-learn.

Comment: Hi @Riyaz, could you give more details?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/riyazbhat/skflow. It has an example for iris data, follow the same procedure for you data. It should not be tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple classification from skflow wrapper for tensor-flow.

```
import skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowLinearClassifier(n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(classifier.predict(iris.data), iris.target)
print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Comment: I found it on the same time, looks good. However I am struggling to install tensorflow. I cannot imagine how difficult to install a Google product like this?

Comment: Follow the instruction give here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html

Comment: Well, the instruction could not help me, but I found the solution and now I can run skflow. Thank you very much,

Comment: Hi @Riyaz, could you help me by an example for using CNN with my type of dataset. I tried to adapt from Character CNN example, but in this case, the example preprocess the data (``byte_list``) before feeding it to CNN.

Comment: @mamatv You should try just reshaping your X into 4d and then applying conv. Something like this https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/examples/digits.py#L34